# How to write this symbol in Mathjax?

Tags: support, mathjax

How to write this symbol in Mathjax?
[image: Another symbol(maybe better one) for Natural numbers set]

I'm already familiar with \Bbb{N} code but prefer the above symbol!
Is it possible to depict it using Mathjax?

Comment: Blackboard Bold isn't bad enough, you want to go back to Typewriter Bold?

Comment: Oh, the things we did before TeX:  $\mathbb{N,R,Z}$ were not too hard.  How did you do $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @GEdgar Is the correct answer (Q?

Comment: What I saw back then was Q backspace I, so that the I comes out in the middle of the Q.  Like this $\;\mathrm{Q\!\!\!I}$  ... Not much like $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typing `$\mathrm{I}\!\mathrm{N}$` yields $\mathrm{I}\!\mathrm{N}$.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: I'd recommend against using this to typeset a "bold" N. This could lead to varied confusion.